# 3D vector representation of $H_2O$ molecule?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetry

I'm struggling with a group theory question on the symmetries of the water molecule. First off, I'm giving the following image of the molecule in question:

[image]

Now, I've constructed the character table of this molecule as follows, where c denotes the rotations and b denotes the reflections that preserve the symmetry of the molecule. Hence, these symmetries form a group called $G_W = {(c,b  |  c^2 =b^2 =(bc)^2 = e)} $.

[image]

Now I'm asked to provide the three dimensional vector representation $D^V$ of the group $G_W$. The solutions state only the following, without explanation, and I am not sure how they got to this answer.

[image]

Can anyone maybe provide some explanation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are several non-isomorphic 3-dimensional representations of this group, all direct sums of three irreducible 1-dimensional reps. The one they show may correspond to the symmetries of the water molecule. Provided that the axes are chosen carefully. After all, those matrices are (from left to right): 180 degree rotation about the $y$-axis, reflection w.r.t. the plane $z=0$, and reflection w.r.t. the plane $x=0$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ahhh I see, thank you!

Comment: Your wording "I'm struggling with ..." & "First off, **[[I'm]]** giving the following image ..." & "Now, **[[I've]]** constructed the character table of this molecule ..." & "Now I'm asked to provide ..." : I am not sure whether you made the Character table & the 3D Image. If you did , then you may already know the Answer to your Question. If you did not & you got that from the text book , then you should write your Post like that. You should include the text Book Details.

Comment: @Prem Did not construct the image myself, however did construct the character table. Images are not from a book but from an exercise sheet. Thanks.